# Printing numbers in new lines

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have two variables say `a=5` and `b=10`.
I want to print them in new lines.

I tried `print (a \n b)` `print(a '\n' b)` `print(a, '\n' b)` `print (a + '\n' +b)`.
None of them works.

I can do `print("a \n b")` if a and b are strings.
For integers, is printing like `print(str(a)+"\n"+str(b))` the only way?
I guess there must be another decent way which I don't know.

Comment: @Emma getting syntax error.

Comment: That's a new syntax (Python 3.6+); if you have an old Python, it won't work.

Comment: Note also the simplest method of all: `print(a); print(b)`

Comment: @Emma your code works fine, can anyone explain what's happening in there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just say `print(*[a, b], sep="\n")`. It unpacks a list (of n elements), and prints out every element. We specify a separator between the elements which in this case is `newline` or `\n`

```
a = 1
b = 2
print(*[a, b], sep="\n")
# output
1
2
```

You can use `print(f"{a}\n{b}")` as well in python 3.6+. Or `print("{0}\n{1}".format(a, b))` in Python < 3.6

Comment: If you know there will be 2 items, there is no advantage of this over `print(a, b, sep="\n")`

Comment: @ram_23 It unpacks a list (of n elements), and prints out every element. We specify a separator between the elements which in this case is `newline` or `\n`.

Answer (score 2):

A simple solution:

```
print(a, b, sep='\n')
```